# National Rail Enquiries issue with SOAP requests. The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)

Tags: ios, swift, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to query National Rail Enquiries using their API found below however I'm having some issues.

http://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/openldbws/

I'm attempting to use the SOAPEngine64 framework (https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine) to simplify the process of making the requests (using Swift) but I don't seem to be able to get any results back.

Every time I run the following code I get this error printed out. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

**Error:**

```
2015-03-28 13:46:09.528 Rapid Rail UK[18994:1032065] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7fd9a9c35e80 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/wsdl.aspx?ver=2014-02-20, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/wsdl.aspx?ver=2014-02-20}
```

**Swift Code:**

```
    var token = "<com:AccessToken><com:TokenValue>MY_TOKEN_KEY</com:TokenValue></com:AccessToken>"

    var soap = SOAPEngine()

    soap.header = token
    soap.actionNamespaceSlash = true

    var args = [
        "numRows" : 10,
        "crs" : "GTW"
    ];

    soap.requestWSDL("https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/wsdl.aspx?ver=2014-02-20",
        operation: "GetDepartureBoard",
        value: args,
        completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int,
            dict : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in

            var result:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
            NSLog("%@", result)

        }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in

            NSLog("%@", error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use requestWSDL, use requestURL, without wsdl extension, call directly the asmx service (https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb6.asmx), and try to set the soapAction to http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2014-02-20/ldb/GetDepartureBoard. This is because the WSDL not contains soapAction attributes, but needed for the correct parsing of the WSDL definitions.